# Rails: jQuery - page resets before event can complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a webpage, and some jQuery that I wrote, and had working functionally until I brought it into my rails application.  I'm not sure if this is some turbolink issue (like I've had before) or if its unrelated.

My jQuery script is for my custom dropdown menu, and while the clicking causes the dropdown to appear, the dropdown doesn't remain, and all the html is reset.  I have a video: http://tinypic.com/r/35ml7jr/8 that shows what I am trying to explain.

### jQuery

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {

    $(".navbar-link").on("click", function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var dd = el.siblings();

        var loc = el.offset();
        var left = loc.left;
        var width = el.width();
        var center = left + (0.5 * width);
        var corrected_center = center - 5;

        var isDown = dd.hasClass('down');
        var numDown = $(document).find(".down").length;

        var screenWidth = $( window ).width();

        // check width to determine how to proceed

        if ( screenWidth > 767 ) {
        // if there ARE dropdowns present, quickly hide / show
            if ( numDown > 0 ) {
                $(".dropdown-nav").removeClass('down');

                // if THIS dropdown is down, animate w/ slide
                if (dd.css("display") === "block") {
                    $(".dropdown-nav").slideUp();

                // if ANOTHER dropdown is down, switch quickly
                } else {
                    $(".dropdown-nav").hide();
                }

                // display the clicked link
                if (!isDown) {
                    dd.addClass('down');
                    dd.show();
                }

            // if there are NO dropdowns present, animate w/ slide
            } else {

                $(".dropdown-nav").removeClass('down');

                // if THIS dropdown is down, animate w/ slide
                if (dd.css("display") === "block") {
                    $(".dropdown-nav").slideUp();

                // if ANOTHER dropdown is down, switch quickly
                } else {
                    $(".dropdown-nav").hide();
                }

                if (!isDown) {
                    dd.addClass('down');
                    dd.slideDown();
                    $(".rest").animate({"top": "105px"});
                }
            }   

            var isActive = el.hasClass('activate');
            $(".navbar-link").removeClass('activate');

            $(".arrow-up").css("left", corrected_center);

            if (isActive) {
                $('.arrow-up').hide(400);
            } else {
                $('.arrow-up').show();
                el.addClass('activate');
            }

        // for small screens
        } else {

            // if there ARE dropdowns present, quickly hide / show
            if ( numDown > 0 ) {
                $(".dropdown-nav").removeClass('down');

                // if THIS dropdown is down, animate w/ slide
                if (dd.css("display") === "block") {
                    $(".dropdown-nav").slideUp();

                // if ANOTHER dropdown is down, switch quickly
                } else {
                    $(".dropdown-nav").slideUp();
                }

                // display the clicked link
                if (!isDown) {
                    dd.addClass('down');
                    dd.slideDown();
                }

            // if there are NO dropdowns present, animate w/ slide
            } else {

                $(".dropdown-nav").removeClass('down');

                // if THIS dropdown is down, animate w/ slide
                if (dd.css("display") === "block") {
                    $(".dropdown-nav").slideUp();

                // if ANOTHER dropdown is down, switch quickly
                } else {
                    $(".dropdown-nav").hide();
                }

                if (!isDown) {
                    dd.addClass('down');
                    dd.slideDown();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why you've bound the code here to a `page:change` event instead of just putting it in the usual dom ready block?  (this might be your problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.on('click',function(){...})`
Try using

```
.on('click',function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); // This should prevent reloading
   //YOUR CODE GOES HERE
   return true; // It informs, that event has ended
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Looks like its working.  Could you explain to me why this is necessary for proper functioning?

Comment: event.preventDefault() is like stop anything, from using this. Generaly when you click a link it reloads webpage. This is preventing it